# Date and mobile numbers are not showing up in my csv file exporting from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am working on a PHP site where I have to export all the users from mysql database.
Everything is working well  but when I open the exported csv file, the mobile number and the date are not showing up in proper format i.e mobile number appears as hexadecimal and the date appears as #####.I want to it in a proper data format any help ? thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using any library or doing the export by yourself ? Could you give us the PhP code you're using ? Without it, we can't help much.

Comment: from excel set the format of that column to text and then it will show up

Comment: You sure the date is really coded as "#####"? This looks more like you open the file in a spread sheet application and the column is too narrow. Slide the column wider a little...

Comment: In general: first thing to do is look at the csv file itself in a raw manner, not with some sophisticateed tool, but a plain text editor or something to see what is really contained in there.

Comment: I suspect that what you mean by `hexadecimal` is really a number in `scientific` format

Comment: We were able to *guess* what your problem is, but you've provided very little info. Next time try to put more effort into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually not that sign, click on it will show you value. CSV just show it as a preview.

Answer (score 2):

You have high expectations about the CSV format. It's nothing but plain text divided into columns, as you can check by yourself if you simply open the resulting file in a text editor (rather than double-clicking it and getting it loaded by the default program). Interpretation of its contents is basically left to the client-side spreadsheet software and you're apparently using the least usable among all: Microsoft Excel.

Excel doesn't prompt for any option when you double-click on a file. It uses default options for everything and most of those defaults are poorly chosen:

- File encoding is the computer's default encoding: Win-1252, EUC-JP...
- Column separator is the computer's default list separator: `,` in the US, `;` in some European countries...
- Dates must be in the computer's default date format: MM/DD/YYYY in the US, DD/MM/YYYY almost everywhere else.
- Leading zeroes are discarded.

If you load the file in e.g. LibreOffice Calc you get a dialogue instead where you can ensure that data gets loaded properly (but, still, it's a manual task you need to do every time).

To sum up: CSV is a terrible format if you don't have control on how it's going to be processed (but it's popular because it's so easy to generate).

As about your exact questions:

> mobile number appears as hexadecimal

I suspect you mean this:

```
6.00912E+15
```

This is not hexadecimal, it's the scientific notation you were taught at school (6.00912 × 10<sup>15</sup>) as it's normally represented in computers. It's how Excel displays large numbers; because, yes, Excel will insist on handling phones as numbers (which they aren't). If you click on the cell, you'll see the full value in the top bar.

Please note that that phone numbers that start with `0` (e.g. international numbers in `00<country code>` format) will not load properly in Excel. It'll drop leading zeroes and changing the cell format to "Text" will not get them back.

> the date appears as #####.

And this is how Excel represents that a column is too narrow to show a value. Just drag the little separator between column headers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
$csv_output = '';
$query_result=mysql_query("select * from tablename");
//add your table field name and proceed forther
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query_result)){
  $csv_output.=",".$result['fildname']." ";
  }
   //$csv_output.="\n";


 header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=csvfile.csv");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Expires: 0");
 print $csv_output;
 exit;
?>
```

i try this hope you can use this thing

Comment: Why can't you use [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)?

Comment: fget() and fput() are blocked in some server for security

Comment: Unless the OP has indicated that he can't use filesystem functions (even to write to php://output) it's surely better to make them aware of the most appropriate function for the task

Comment: you are right but in some case because i have a same issue i used this and creat the csv file in my way . i had generate the sales report and   it help me